# Access a service from inside a directive's compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a hard time to access a service inside a directive. I define my service via $http and $q, and inject it into my directive. But I can;t get the directive to access the service.

service.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('App.services', []);

app.factory('Classification', function($http,$q) {
    return {
        query: function getAll() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('index.php/classifications').then(function(classi) { 
                deferred.resolve(classi.data);
            }, function getWebsitesError(reason) {
                deferred.reject(reason);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */
var app = angular.module('App', ['App.controllers', 'App.services', 'App.directives',  'ui']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html'}).
      when('/websites/:websiteId', {templateUrl: 'partials/website/details.html',     controller: 'WebsiteDetailsCtrl'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

and my directive.js :

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('App.directives', ['App.services']);

app.directive("regionselect",['Classification', '$compile', function($compile, Classification){
    Classification.query();<-- Throw an exception : has no method query()
    return{
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl : "/js/directives/locationSelect3.html",
        transclude: true,
        compile: function (tElement, tAttr, transclude){
            var loaded = false;                
        }
    };
}]);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be the ordering?

```
app.directive("regionselect",['Classification', '$compile', function($compile, Classification){
```

You declare

```
['Classification', '$compile',
```

but the the function says

```
function($compile, Classification){
```

Which is backwards.

Comment: OMG !!!! It has beena long time since I haven't asked such a stupid question! Thanks Mate!